# match a word an not the entire line in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a text file formatted as such:

```
#    title "Secondary Structure"
#    xaxis  label "Time (ns)"
#    yaxis  label "Number of Residues"
#TYPE xy
# subtitle "Structure = A-Helix + B-Sheet + B-Bridge + Turn"
# view 0.15, 0.15, 0.75, 0.85
# legend on
# legend box on
# legend loctype view
# legend 0.78, 0.8
# legend length 2
# s0 legend "Structure"
# s1 legend "Coil"
# s2 legend "B-Sheet"
# s3 legend "B-Bridge"
# s4 legend "Bend"
# s5 legend "Turn"
# s6 legend "A-Helix"
# s7 legend "5-Helix"
# s8 legend "3-Helix"
# s9 legend "Chain_Separator"
   0   637   180   201     7    94   129   300     0    47     1
   1   617   189   191    11    99   121   294     5    48     1
   2   625   183   198     7    97   130   290     0    53     1
   3   625   180   195     5   102   125   300     0    51     1
   4   622   185   196     5    99   117   304     0    52     1
   5   615   192   190     5   106   121   299     0    45     1
   6   629   187   196     7   102   122   304     0    40     1
```

I'm trying to to match the lines starting with "s+number" (s0,s1,s2,...s9) and save the values between "" in a list so I can then use this list for naming the columns.

`list <- c("Structure", "Coil","B-Sheet", ..., "Chain_Separato")
names(data) <- list`

The problem is that I can't match the single words but only the entire lines.

`grep('s\\d\\s[a-z]{6}\\s\"([A-z-9]+)\"',readLines("file.xvg"),perl=T,value=T)`

```
[1] "# s0 legend \"Structure\""       "# s1 legend \"Coil\""  
[3] "# s2 legend \"B-Sheet\""         "# s3 legend \"B-Bridge\""
[5] "# s4 legend \"Bend\""            "# s5 legend \"Turn\""
[7] "# s6 legend \"A-Helix\""         "# s9 legend \"Chain_Separator\""
```

I tried several regex, like `'# s[0-9] [a-z]+ "([A-z-9]+)"'`, all working in perl but in R I'm always matching the entire line and not the word.

Isn't the () used to capture the value? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's why I used `perl=T`

Comment: Do the lines really begin with `#` or did you add that in for the post?

Comment: really start with `#`; it's a xvg formatted to be read by `grace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
conn = file(fileName,open="r")
lines=readLines(conn)

lst = Filter(function(u) grepl('^# s[0-9]+', u), lines)
result = gsub('.*\"(.*)\".*','\\1',lst)

close(conn)

#> result
#[1] "Structure"       "Coil"            "B-Sheet"         "B-Bridge"        "Bend"            "Turn"            "A-Helix"         "5-Helix"        
#[9] "3-Helix"         "Chain_Separator"
```

Comment: thank you, it works.
basically you are first matching all the lines starting with s[0-9] and then using `gsub` grepping the part between " " with ()and \\1.

Comment: Exactly, I did this in two steps for clearer solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a system command in `fread()`. For example, on a file named "file.txt" you can do

```
library(data.table)
fread("grep '^# s[0-9]\\+' file.txt", header = FALSE, select = 4)[[1]]
#  [1] "Structure"       "Coil"            "B-Sheet"        
#  [4] "B-Bridge"        "Bend"            "Turn"           
#  [7] "A-Helix"         "5-Helix"         "3-Helix"        
# [10] "Chain_Separator"
```

Note: This uses [data.table dev version 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Basically the area you're looking for in the text has four columns. `^# s[0-9]\\+` looks for lines that begin with `#` and then a space, then `s`, then any number of digits. `select = 4` takes the last column, and `[[1]]` drops it down from a single column data table into a character vector.

Thanks to @BrodieG for help with the regex.

Comment: thank you Richard, is it correct to say that:
fread is taking all lines starting with "s[0-9]" and selecting the 4th column? So the warning would be because the "subtitle" line only have 3 columns..right?
But then what's the [[1]] doing?

Comment: We may need to adjust the regex, but basically the area you're looking for has four columns. I have updated the answer and there is no longer a warning. `^#.s[0-9]` says  that the line starts with `#` then `.` (anything), then `s[0-9]`.  `select = 4` takes the last column, and `[[1]]` drops it down from a single column data table into a character vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `linux`,  `awk`  commands can be combined with `read.table` using `pipe`

```
read.table(pipe("awk 'BEGIN {FS=\" \"}/# s[0-9]/  { print$4 }' fra.txt"),
          stringsAsFactors=FALSE)$V1
 # [1] "Structure"       "Coil"            "B-Sheet"         "B-Bridge"  
 # [5] "Bend"            "Turn"            "A-Helix"         "5-Helix"    
 # [9] "3-Helix"         "Chain_Separator"
```

The above command also works with `fread`

```
fread("awk 'BEGIN {FS=\" \"}/# s[0-9]/  { print$4 }' fra.txt", 
                 header=FALSE)$V1
```